# Multiplos objetos em seletor jquery

Tags: jquery

Por questão de organização e por desempenho costumo usar varios seletores juntos para realizar um método jquery. Por exemplo:

```
$("#bola, #casa, #arvore").css("background-color", "blue");
```

Neste exemplo funciona pois o seletor é uma string.

Porém ao utilizar objetos eu não sei como fazer essa junção.

Novo cenário:

```
var bola = $("#bola");
var casa = $("#casa");
var arvore = $("#arvore");

$(bola, casa, arvore).css("background-color", "blue");
```

Neste caso apenas o fundo de "bola" é pintado.

Ou concatenando com vírgula:

```
$(bola+ ","+ casa + "," + arvore).css("background-color", "blue");
```

Neste caso nenhum dos dois é pintado, como já era esperado.

Então gostaria de saber se há alguma forma de juntar esses objetos por virgula ou de alguma forma que fiquem no mesmo seletor.

Fiddle de teste: http://jsfiddle.net/nsMw3/

OBS: Não vale colocar que var itens = $("#bola, #casa"), pois utilizo objetos que são trazidos de forma bem mais complexa, e defino eles um a um.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode usar o método [add()](http://api.jquery.com/add/) para combinar objetos em um conjunto

```
var bola = $("#bola");
var casa = $("#casa");

$(bola).add(casa).css("background-color", "blue");
```

**[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nsMw3/1/)**

#### Opção

jQuery não permite adicionar vários elementos de uma só vez para um objeto jQuery, uma opção seria adicionar vários elementos DOM puro à uma array:

```
var bola = $('#bola'),
    casa = $('#casa'),
    arvore = $('#arvore');

// array de elementos DOM 
$( [bola[0], casa[0], arvore[0]] ).css("background-color", "blue");
```

Ao fazer `bola[0]` você esta acessando o elemento DOM `div#bola`

**[JSFiddle 2](http://jsfiddle.net/nsMw3/3/)**

Comment: +1 O bom do método `add` é que ele preserva o stack: http://jsfiddle.net/nsMw3/2/

Comment: Solução matadora! +1

Comment: No caso de id não precisa passar como var, apenas o ID do elemento nó e não há necessidade de passar posição do INDEX, logo que você não pode repetir ID's e é dispensável passar o index.

Comment: @abfurlan essa solução do array com o [0] acho que é o máximo que dá pra chegar em termos de legibilidade, organização e desempenho. Obrigado!

Comment: @JoaoPaulo legal, tb descobri agora esta forma de fazer e achei interessante postar, sempre que precisei usei com add

Answer (score 3):

Para isso utilize o método `.merge()`[1](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.merge/)

```
var bola = $("#bola");
var casa = $("#casa");

$.merge(bola, casa).css("background-color", "blue");
```

Estou adicionando o código dos comentários que coloquei:

Para usar com dois ou mais ID's:
**HTML**:

```
<div id="bola">bola</div>
<div id="casa">casa</div>
<div id="rodape">rodape</div>
<div id="aa">rodape</div>
```

**JS**:

```
$([bola, casa, rodape, aa]).css("background-color", "blue");
```

Dessa forma você não precisa declarar os ids em vars e seu código fica mais limpo.

Comment: Ronny, tinha marcado como correta, porém eu testei com 3 elementos e não funcionou. Editei minha pergunta para que fique claro minha necessidade de multiplos elementos e não apenas dois.

Comment: @JoaoPaulo Talvez `$.merge(bola, casa, arvore)` não funcione, mas que tal `$.merge($.merge(bola, casa), arvore)`? (Nota: segundo a documentação linkada, o método `merge` modifica o primeiro elemento - de modo que se você precisa usá-lo em outra operação qualquer, não use esse método)

Comment: A intenção principal é fazer isso de forma que fique bem legível e de fácil compreensão para manutenção. A principio varios merges iria bagunçar muito. Vou continuar pesquisando, mas se não encontrar nada melhor marcarei essa resposta pois ela já ajuda e agrega conhecimento.

Comment: Amigo, perca um pouco do seu tempo para ver a documentação, ajuda muito. Agora olhe este meu exemplo, olha que mágica, nem preciso declarar váriaveis, é só ler a documentação...: http://jsfiddle.net/nsMw3/4/

Comment: Estou pesquisando na documentação desde que fiz a pergunta. Muito legal o seu exemplo, porém ele se utiliza das ids. Como mencionei, no meu caso real de uso os objetos são obtidos de forma mais complexa. Na real acho que não terei como fazer de forma organizada como espero, separando em virgulas num unico seletor, mas obrigado pelas dicas e resposta.

Comment: E de qualquer forma, referir-se ao elementos diretamente pelo `id` - sem usar `document.getElementById` - não é considerado uma boa prática. [Essa resposta no SOen](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7827037/520779) dá algumas razões para tal.

Comment: @mgibsonbr você está se baseando em uma resposta de 2011, poderia me apontar 1 problema resultante do mesmo? :)

Comment: @RonnyAmarante A resposta é de 2011, mas a funcionalidade em questão é bem mais antiga. Achei os argumentos da resposta convincentes, em particular a questão da poluição do namespace global. Mas isso é questão de opinião, não tenho como te dar uma razão objetiva. Na [discussão linkada na resposta](https://www.w3.org/Bugs/Public/show_bug.cgi?id=11960) também há várias opiniões conflitantes (pra mim não ficou claro se essa funcionalidade foi incorporada no HTML5, se ficou só no 'quirks mode", ou se foi eliminada).

Comment: @mgibsonbr está incorporado sim, e eu não achei nenhuma razão, se você achar me avise. ;)

Comment: @mgibsonbr tente fazer esse teste: `var casa = "a";
alert($([casa]))` logo se eu fizer `var casa = document.getElementById("casa")` ele vai ler a váriavel casa ou pegar o elemento diretamente?

Comment: @RonnyAmarante Abri [uma pergunta separada](http://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/22583/215) para tratar disso. Não adianta eu discutir com você, pois não tenho experiência prática suficiente para embasar minhas opiniões. Se quiser dar uma resposta lá e/ou ver o que os outros escrevem a respeito, fique à vontade. P.S. Não entendi a pergunta - se você define algo com `var`, a definição é o que conta; somente se *não existir* nada com o nome `casa` é que o elemento com mesmo `id` será considerado.